# Quid aliud edam?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, idiom

A semi-sated lower-class Roman stands in front of the pantry and mutters to themselves: "What else could I eat?"

What would be the most natural or idiomatic way of expressing this sentiment?

What I've found so far: "Quid aliud edam?" or "Quid nunc edam?" or "Nunc quid edam?"

Comment: This is a very interesting question. When I first read *quid aliud edam* I read it as, "what else would I eat?" As in, "of course it's food! What else would I eat?" But you want it to mean, "what else is there to eat?" I'm not sure it can mean that, but I'm also not sure it can't either. Very thought provoking.

Comment: Thanks @Figulus, you're confirming my suspicion that _quid aliud_ may be read as a rhetorical question. Here I am definitely looking for a true question, as you understood well.

Comment: I still can't say that *quid aliud edam* is wrong, but I wonder whether *quid plus edam* might be better, or *quae plura edam*?

Comment: Caseum Hollandicum edam, nonne?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been pondering this for a while, and I turned to Traupman for advice.

Under *else* in the English-to-Latin section of his dictionary, Traupman gives *aliquid amplius* for *anything else*.

So I'll suggest *Quid amplius edam* for *what else can I eat*.

Comment: I agree with this, with the elaboration that "quid amplius" means "what in addition", whereas "quid aliud" means "what other than [some contextually understood reference point]". Either could be correct for a given context, but quid amplius sounds right here.

Comment: @Figulus: Is "quid amplius edam" an indirect question? For, "What is there to eat?", a present subjunctive passive, giving: "quid aliud edatur?" = "What else may be eaten?". Is this correct?

Comment: @tony I'm not sure the subjunctive is an indirect question, I'd rather call it a deliberative. But then I'm not so sure the line between deliberatives and indirect questions is necessarily very thick.